# Resulting dataframe from two dataframes with distinct columns names and row sizes, but with few coincident values, presented in parallel (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

There are two dataframes with players id and all the points they've gained during the two days of tournament (monday and friday).
I want to end up with a final dataframe with the following format.

```
    final =
       match_monday    points      match_friday     points   
    0  player#0005     13.0        player#0005      19.0
    1  player#0067     26.0        player#0067      0.0
    2  player#0098     0.0         player#0098      23.0  
    4  player#0104     24.0        player#0104      0.0
    5  player#0211     14.0        player#0211      0.0 
    6  player#0227     17.0        player#0227      21.0
```

The starting point are these two dataframes:

```
    df1 =  
       match_monday     points           
    0  player#0227      17.0  
    1  player#0005      13.0  
    2  player#0104      24.0  
    3  player#0067      26.0  
    4  player#0211      14.0  

    df2 =  
       match_friday     points           
    0  player#0227      21.0  
    1  player#0098      23.0  
    2  player#0005      19.0  


    #Dataframes scripts:
    df1 = pd.DataFrame([['player#0227',17.0],['player#0005',13.0],['player#0104',24.0],['player#0067',26.0],['player#0211',14.0]],columns=['match_monday','points'])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame([['player#0227',21.0],['player#0098',23.0],['player#0005',19.0]],columns=['match_friday','points'])
```

I've merged the two dataframes and realized I would need a lot of steps from here until to get to the desired format. 
The result of the merge:

```
        match_monday  points match_friday
    0  player#0227    17.0          NaN
    1  player#0005    13.0          NaN
    2  player#0104    24.0          NaN
    3  player#0067    26.0          NaN
    4  player#0211    14.0          NaN
    5          NaN    21.0  player#0227
    6          NaN    23.0  player#0098
    7          NaN    19.0  player#0005
```

I was trying to order match_friday, with this sentence, to put in a "for loop", when I realized my approach wasn't that good.

```
    matchMon = df2[df2.match_friday.isin(df1.match_monday)]

    print(machMon)
    match_friday  points
    0  player#0227    21.0
    2  player#0005    19.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think better is use different approach - create `Series` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and last replace missing values by `fillna` - then get indices of all players:

```
a = df1.set_index('match_monday')['points'].rename('po_mon')
b = df2.set_index('match_friday')['points'].rename('po_fri')

df = pd.concat([a, b], axis=1, sort=False).fillna(0)
print (df)
             po_mon  po_fri
player#0227    17.0    21.0
player#0005    13.0    19.0
player#0104    24.0     0.0
player#0067    26.0     0.0
player#0211    14.0     0.0
player#0098     0.0    23.0
```